# Отношения входного текста к каждой из категорий в предсказании нейронной сети с predict()

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Используя следующую строку:

```
loaded_model.predict(tokenize_text)
```

получаю предсказание нейронной сети такого вида:

```
[[1.4275383e-02 5.4952472e-01 4.3477431e-01 4.6290222e-04 7.9817160e-05
  7.9108047e-04 9.1869697e-05]]
```

Что это такое? Это вероятность отношения входного текста к каждой из категории или это что-то другое?

Как дальше работать с таким ответом?

---

PS Использую `categorical_crossentropy` классификацию.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это матрица вероятностей принадлежности образца к каждой из предсказываемых категорий.

Обычно в каждой строке выбирают самую высокую вероятность и считают это результатом предсказания.

Пример:

```
In [59]: pred = np.random.rand(5,7)

In [60]: pred
Out[60]:
array([[0.25116354, 0.47708623, 0.21226491, 0.08802933, 0.45567165, 0.38426133, 0.49696775],
       [0.68885503, 0.86980125, 0.33731364, 0.38061702, 0.3829377 , 0.9580115 , 0.64637692],
       [0.56123832, 0.46719667, 0.56376401, 0.37573342, 0.62549972, 0.7701246 , 0.05129524],
       [0.02000297, 0.7092602 , 0.70582711, 0.0267432 , 0.1180354 , 0.4468312 , 0.4808733 ],
       [0.08240929, 0.6039415 , 0.59389567, 0.75639147, 0.06921623, 0.82351478, 0.75909791]])

In [61]: pred.argmax(axis=1)
Out[61]: array([6, 5, 5, 1, 5], dtype=int64)
```

> можно ли как проверить эти значения, и если они меньше определённого
>   числа, например указать что нейросеть не уверена в ответе?

Можно возвращать `-1` если вероятность ниже установленного порогового значения:

```
In [71]: threshold = 0.5

In [72]: np.where(pred.max(axis=1) >= threshold, pred.argmax(axis=1), -1)
Out[72]: array([-1,  5,  5,  1,  5], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: можно ли как проверить эти значения, и если они меньше определённого числа, например указать что нейросеть не уверена в ответе?